# How to tell the contract deployed size? (Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount.)

Tags: evm, truffle-migration, bytecode

I get `Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount.` whenever I deploy to any test network (rinkeby, ropsten) or the live network. Deploy to a local Ganache works perfect.

According to other SE, [GH](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/558) and Medium posts, I realize this doesn't necessarily means I'm lacking gas, rather that the deployed EVM byte code is too large.

I'm using Truffle of course.

How can I tell how large the deployed code is???

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer by chance in a [github thread](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/issues/358#issuecomment-335472271) . Apparently the constructor would fail and it simply that the error message is so misleading!

A screenshot of the relevant error and solution from the linked thread:

[image]